# how do I enable Debug JS Remotely in React Native?

Tags: react-native, debugging, redux

To debug redux, I use React Native Debugger, but for this you need to enable Debug JS Remotely. I don't have this tab in the developer menu. I use redux, redux-toolkit, redux-saga.

photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrX4b.png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should disable hermes on Podfile:

- Set `:hermes_enabled => false`
- Install pods `cd ios && pod install && cd ..`
- Build App `npx react-native run-ios`

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34615#issuecomment-1238913946

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

We can debug the application with ReactNative 0.70.0 with Hermes Enabled by following this [reference](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes#debugging-js-on-hermes-using-google-chromes-devtools)

Comment: This is the correct answer in 2024 - the post below outlines the same thing step-by-step inline but this answer was posted three months before.

The main thing to know for anyone trying to figure out why this is the Right Way to do things is that react-native now implements the chrome debugging protocol directly - so no more third-party modules of any sort to get full fidelity debugging.

Answer (score 4):

Install `yarn add react-native-devsettings` and in your `App.tsx` add
`import 'react-native-devsettings';`

then press `cmd+d` and select `(*) Debug JS Remotely`, it should work for React Native 0.71 and other versions.

https://github.com/gusgard/react-native-devsettings#usage

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Chrome:

1. Navigate to `chrome://inspect` in a Chrome browser instance.
2. Click on `Configure...`
3. Add `localhost:8081` on Target discovery settings and click Done.
4. Your App will be displayed on Remote Target. Note: Please make sure that
   you're running Metro.
5. Click Inspect

References: https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes

Comment: This is the right way, but missing part is the network tab to inspect network calls

Answer (score 0):

Shake your device or pick `"Shake Gesture"` from the `Hardware` menu in the iOS Simulator to get to the developer menu. you can check this tutorial [here](https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/web-development/debugging-react-native).

Answer (score 0):

Choose `Open Debugger` option and then inspect the browser webpage and go to the `console` tab in that

Comment: Unfortunately, here's what happens in the console:
`info Opening flipper://null/Hermesdebuggerrn?device=React%20Native...`
`error Browser exited with error:, Error: invalid url, missing http/https protocol`

Answer (score 0):

installed the desktop version of `flipper` with the `redux debugger plugin`.  The problem is solved, albeit in a different way :)

Comment: Flipper is the most unsuccessful program I've ever seen in my life.

Comment: Flipper is long deprecated. This is a dead-end for anyone arriving in 2024 imho. I'd suggest deleting this answer as its just very outdated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [website](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes) and You can check the hermes installation settings. You have to configure [chrome settings](https://chrome://inspect/) for using debug mode with hermes.